# C# threads - Posting messages between threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, mfc

I am working on a project which involves reusing as well as migrating some of the existing MFC code to C#.

The current code in MFC, creates some threads and uses ::PostthreadeMessage() and ON_THREAD_MESSAGE(msg,func) for inter thread asynchronous communication through messages.

::PostthreadeMessage() -> sends a message to a particular thread id.
ON_THREAD_MESSAGE(msg,func) -> calls the function(func) when a message(msg) is received.

Since i am not much aware of the threading interfaces in C#, i tried to search for similar API's in C#, but was not able to find any.

It would be great, if somebody can help me in finding the appropriate functions for this purpose in C#

Comment: that relies upon the receiving thread having a msg pump (and therefore a window) does it not?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the advice from [C# MVP Nicholas Paldino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone):

> If you are posting to the thread, and
>   not to a specific window, then you
>   will have to have something that
>   implements the IMessageFilter
>   interface, and then pass that
>   implementation to the static
>   AddMessageFilter method on the
>   Application class, so it can handle
>   the message that comes in on the
>   thread.
>
> From the other thread, you will have
>   to use the PostThreadMessage API
>   method through the P/Invoke layer.

Comment: There is a risk to this approach. PostThreadMessage posts a message using the threadId, but the relationship between the threadId and a managed thread is not fixed. From MSDN "An operating-system ThreadId has no fixed relationship to a managed thread, because an unmanaged host can control the relationship between managed and unmanaged threads."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74169f59.aspx

Comment: Thanks to Chris and Mitch!!!

Just needed couple of more clarifications on your suggestions.

You mentioned about the PostThreadMessage API. Is it the one from user32 dll, which i can dllimport and use it?

If so, then where exactly should i implement IMessageFilter interface and why?

Without implementing it, can't i import the getmessage and postthreadmessage from user32 dll and use it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you against doing a direct port for this (inter thread communication) part of the application. May be you can check if you can use delegates and events. A delegate could be registered at startup and these delegates (callbacks) could be called instead of the user message.

Answer (score 1):

If both of your threads are in C# and you are on .NET 4 I would just use a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` and queue up messages from one thread and then consume them on the other.

Comment: Thanks for the info!! I am on .NET3.5. My threads will be created in C# and needs to communicate to each other. Also each thread will use some MFC dll, and from that MFC code, i want to communicate to the other thread in C# using thread id.

Hope it gives you some idea!!!